# The message could not be processed because the action '' is invalid or unrecognized soap service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, soapui

I am getting `The message could not be processed because the action '' is invalid or unrecognized.` this error while executing soap webservice from rest client

My request is as follow..4

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
   <wsse:Security xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
   <wsse:BinarySecurityToken wsu:Id="x509cert00" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509" >
     MICCBD6gAwIBAgIHBISUaU/3vTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBtDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEDAOBgNVBAgTB0FyaXpvbmExEzARBgNVBAcTClNjb3R0....
    </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>

    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:SignedInfo xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                 xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
                 xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
                 xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                   <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
    <c14n:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:c14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="ds wsu xenc SOAP-ENV "/>
   </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                   <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>

      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:KeyInfo>
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      <wsse:Reference URI="#x509cert00" 
                      ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509"/>
    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
   </ds:KeyInfo>

       </ds:Signature>
      </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
<soap:Body>

</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can i resolve this error?

How can I authenticate x509 certificate?
help me to solve this issue..
Any help appreciated

I have this error..

```
<s:Subcode>
                    <s:Value 
                        xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:InvalidSecurity
                    </s:Value>
                </s:Subcode>
            </s:Code>
            <s:Reason>
                <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">The message could not be processed because the action '' is invalid or unrecognized.</s:Text>
            </s:Reason>
```

Comment: Pl. check the raw request, may be soapAction is missing?

Comment: Thanks for reply,.Can you tell me how can I authenticate my service through x509 certificate

Comment: check [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/soapui-projects/ws-security.html)